# Is it possible to programatically change the ResourceFolder property of a content type?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I need to write a tool that **renames a content type in all site collections in a Web application**.

If I only change the Name property, the content type loses access to the resource files. So my guess that I have to rename the resource folder, too. I tried to use MoveTo, but the SchemaXml still contains old URL:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0100754A0B6C5E55E74399195A55F9718184" Name="NEW-NAME" ...>
  <Folder TargetName="_cts/OLD-NAME" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be easier (and more maintainable to just create a new content type (perhaps even based on the old one), then reset all items referencing the old content type to the new, then "deprecate" the old one (by making it hidden)?